# iTextSharp for converting aspx with highcharts to pdf

Tags: pdf-generation

please refer me free dll or tool that could help me in converting aspx page with highcharts filling via javascripts on runtime on page into pdf file.

Public Sub lnkExport_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lnkExport.Click
        Dim attachment As String = "attachment; filename=" & "abc" & ".pdf"
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment)
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Dim s_tw As New StringWriter()
        Dim h_textw As New HtmlTextWriter(s_tw)
        h_textw.AddStyleAttribute("font-size", "7pt")
        h_textw.AddStyleAttribute("color", "Black")
        MasterDiv.RenderControl(h_textw)

```
    'Name of the Panel
    Dim doc As New Document()
    doc = New Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 5, 15, 5)
    FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 80, iTextSharp.text.Color.RED)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, Response.OutputStream)
    doc.Open()
    Dim s_tr As New StringReader(s_tw.ToString())
    Dim html_worker As New HTMLWorker(doc)
    html_worker.Parse(s_tr)
    doc.Close()
    Response.Write(doc)
End Sub


    html_worker.Parse(s_tr) is giving error
```

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of charts are difficult because they use techniques like AJAX which have a rather indeterminate finish point. As such it's hard for an automated tool to know when they are complete.

So these things do rather depend on the particular type of chart you're doing. Some are easier. Some are more difficult. More interactive features = more difficult.

Having said that we did some work on our Gecko HTML rendering engine specifically to aid compatibility with Highcharts. So you might want to take a look at ABCpdf.

I work on the ABCpdf .NET software component so my replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's just what I know. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Vá em todas as livrarias como highcharts.js, highcharts-all.js,heatmap.js e drilldown.js procure a palavra animation:{duration: e substitua o valor que tem dentro de (animation:{duration:1E3 OU animation:{duration:50 ou animation:{duration:500) substitua todos POR animation:{duration:0

Tem com setar sem animação no código mas não funcionou só setar no código, depois que substitui tudo por 0 ai sim funcionou e carregou todas as linhas do gráfico.

Antes da substituição o itextsharp não esperava terminar a animação para carregar todas as linhas do gráfico e ficava incompleto.

colunas:
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        animation: false
    }
}
series

plotOptions: {
    series: {
        animation: false
    }
}

Em inglês:
Go all bookstores as highcharts.js, Highcharts-all.js, heatmap.js and drilldown.js search for the word animation: {duration: and replace the value that is inside (animation: {duration: 1E3 OR animation: { duration: 50 or animation: {duration: 500) replace all FOR animation: {duration: 0

It has to set with no animation in the code did not work only to set the code after replacing all for 0 oh yes it worked and carried all the chart lines.

Before replacing the itextsharp not expect to finish the animation to load all the graph lines and was incomplete.

column:
plotOptions: {
     line: {
         animation: false
     }
}
series

plotOptions: {
     Series: {
         animation: false
     }
}

Comment: Please use english in your posts.